# poner + indirect object pronoun

Tags: objetos-indirectos

I saw the following sentence:

> Mi café está amargo. ¿Puedes ponerle azúcar?

I suppose the 'le' refers to the coffee?

In the following sentence I want to introduce the indirect object. How would I say 'to put the bottles in the box'? I attempted it the following way although I'm sure it's not correct:

> Ponerle las botellas la caja

Is it better to just say the following? is it even correct?

> Poner las botellas en la caja

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add "le" you are refering to someone or something.

> Mi café está amargo. ¿Puedes ponerle [reffering to the cofee] azúcar?

to put the bottles in the box you can and are interchangeables

> - Poner las botellas en la caja
> - Ponerle las botellas **a** la caja
> - Ponerle las botellas [reffering to the box]

Comment: muchas gracias @malkev, so when the indirect object is a thing (not a person) we still need the preposition 'a'? I suppose I was confused with the personal 'a'.

Comment: You always need the 'a'. Ponerle la ropa a Jorge. You didn't have the 'a' on ponerle azúcar, because you are already implying the coffee. "¿Puedes ponerle azúcar al [a el] café?"